# Can Maven install my plugin as a system tool?

Tags: maven, operating-system, rubygems, installation

I want my plugin, which is placed in the Maven Central repo, to be installed as a system tool. I.e. to create a shortcut to a jar's executable class when obtaining it from the repo.

So I need something very similar to a nice Ruby's gem tool. Like when I type

```
sudo gem install capistrano
```

I instantly get 'cap' tool on the command line. Is there any way to achieve similar behaviour in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed such tool [here](https://github.com/chaschev/maven-installation-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

You could distribute a shell script, using Maven, but there would be no mechanism to make it executable.

My suggested work-around on unix systems would be an alias:

```
alias ivy='java -jar $HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.jar $*'
```

enabling you to execute the jar as follows:

```
$ ivy -version
Ivy 2.2.0 - 20100923230623 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/
```

Comment: An interesting idea. And with each update of my lib I need to manually update this alias. So I think I would need to distribute an installation script for this, which would download the artifact and create a shortcut.